# problem with REBASE-i

Tags: git

when I navigate to my project it shows REBASE |REBASE-i, this is happening to me for the first time, because today I was trying to make git reset but I forgot that and I wrote git rebase -i, and some other git rebase options because I couldnt remember how was the command to reset it, because the last time that I used GIT was long time ago! it is working normally but I am worried about this I dont know why it is there now! here is how it looks like:

`Islami@QENDRA /d/xampp/htdocs/Falco (master |REBASE-i)` and it is supposed to be like this:

```
Islami@QENDRA /d/xampp/htdocs/Falco (master)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

git rebase --abort will restore your branch. See http://progit.org/book/ch3-6.html

Comment: I wanted to accept it but I got an notification telling me that I can accept an answer after 10 minutes! so now the 10 minutes passed and I accepted it :)